# GAPI - Different results on the same requestReportData depending on localhost or server?

Tags: google-api, analytics

I have excactly the same file on localhost and on the server, but i get different results from requestReportData, localhost returns 49 records, on the server i only get 17 records.. How can that be?

```
$ga->requestReportData(55443322, array('customVarValue5', 'customVarValue1', 'pagePath', 'networkLocation', 'keyword'), array('timeOnPage'), array('customVarValue5', 'customVarValue1'), null, null, null, 1, 300);
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this might not be an answer but it had to be some kind of bug, now, a day later with the same code on the same computer i get the same amount of records(79) returned.